# Why does sx prop typecheck fail?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, emotion

I'm trying to use [`sx` prop](https://next.material-ui.com/system/the-sx-prop/)-based styling in a React app.°

I'd like to access the theme via a so-called [theme getter](https://next.material-ui.com/system/basics/#theme-getter).

When I try using this approach I can see the styles render OK in the browser. However TypeScript complains and I'm finding it challenging to understand the type ancestry and work out what it's saying.

[Working](https://codesandbox.io/s/sx-prop-brtpx?file=/app.tsx) sandbox

[Not working](https://codesandbox.io/s/sx-prop-theme-getter-4sqrg?file=/app.tsx) sandbox

[image: demo of problem]

Full error:

```js
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<BoxTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject<Theme>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<BoxTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '(theme: any) => { border: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject<Theme>'.
      Type '(theme: any) => { border: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSSelectorObject<Theme>'.ts(2769)
app.tsx(8, 22): Did you mean to call this expression?
```

Possibly relevant GH discussion [1](https://github.com/system-ui/theme-ui/pull/1002#discussion_r439948001), [2](https://github.com/system-ui/theme-ui/pull/910)

Presumably I should by explicitly setting `SystemStyleObject`, but not sure where to import it from. Any pointers would be appreciated.

° The app uses TypeScript `4.4.1-rc` + MUI `5.0.0-beta.4`

Comment: This works for me: `import { SystemStyleObject } from '@mui/system'`

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
import { SxProps } from '@mui/system';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const style: SxProps<Theme> = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: '100%',
  maxWidth: 900,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '1px solid #a7a7a7',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
}

...

<Box sx={style}>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!
We were hoping to avoid the need to depend on those types across all of our components. We're switching to the styled() API to avoid this issue

Answer (score 0):

The way it's typed. Theming function can only be applied to a CSS style and not a class. You can move it down to the border like so:

```
  <Box
    sx={{
      border: "1px solid red",
      ".some-child": {
        border: (theme) => {
          return "1px solid green";
        }
      }
    }}
  >
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that too but wasn't sure how to use it in cases where `theme` is needed in the key, e.g. breakpoints - see https://codesandbox.io/s/sx-prop-theme-getter-with-breakpoint-y1w8p?file=/app.tsx:179-254

Comment: Is there some way I can extend the type to allow theme functions on my own classes? Is that a bad idea? this doc section made me wonder if its feasible https://next.material-ui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables

Comment: @paws that's the issue I'm encountering myself, don't think it's supported at the moment https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27651